# How to use PowerShell to perform an Unsecure Join?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to be able to pre-create a computer account with predetermined account name and password and then perform an "Unsecure Join" to join the computer to the domain.

Using a "Domain Admin" account, I'm able to execute the following to pre-create a domain Computer Account:

```
$acctName = 'EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50'
$password = 'FOOBARNON'
$passwordSS = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force

New-ADComputer -Name $acctName -AccountPassword $passwordSS
```

I can verify the computer account is created in AD with expected Name, SAM Account Name, DN, etc.

Then on the computer that is joining the domain, I execute this:

```
## This is just to confirm the expected hostname for this code sample
if ((& hostname) -ne 'EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50') {
    throw "Unexpected hostname!"
}

$password = 'FOOBARNON'
$passwordSS = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$passCred = New-Object PSCredential($acctName, $passwordSS)

Add-Computer -DomainName "sub.example.local" -Options UnsecuredJoin,PasswordPass -Credential $passCred
```

Unfortunately this returns an error:

> Add-Computer : Computer 'EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50' failed to join domain 'sub.example.local' from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP' with following error message: The parameter is incorrect.

Inspecting the local log file at `C:\Windows\debug\NetSetup.LOG` doesn't give much more helpful detail:

```
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 -----------------------------------------------------------------
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpDoDomainJoin
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpDoDomainJoin: using current computer names
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(NetBios) returned 0x0
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(DnsHostName) returned 0x0
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50'
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpJoinDomain
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372     HostName: EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372     NetbiosName: EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372     Domain: sub.example.local
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372     Account: EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372     Options: 0xc1
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Unsecure join requested.
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Machine password and the user account are passed.  Error out.
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x57
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpResetIDNEncoding on '(null)': 0x0
05/19/2018 23:32:59:372 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x57
NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
```

I seem to be working with the parameters as they are described in the cmdlet docs, but still no dice.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2018/05/20**

It appears that if I try to run a similar domain join operation using the CLI tool `netdom.exe` I'm successful.  Here's a similar netdom variation:

```
netdom join EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50 /Domain "sub.example.local\dc1" /PasswordM:FOOBARNON /ReadOnly
```

This variation is not quite the same as it is actually doing a *readonly* join which is normally used with a RODC (but works with a Global Catalog as well) and a readonly join requires you to qualify a specific target DC, which is the reason for the appended `\dc1` in the domain name.

However this works, and it produces the following `C:\Windows\debug\NetSetup.LOG` detail (partial):

```
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 -----------------------------------------------------------------
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpDoDomainJoin
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpDoDomainJoin: using current computer names
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(NetBios) returned 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(DnsHostName) returned 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50'
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpJoinDomain
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537     HostName: EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537     NetbiosName: EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537     Domain: sub.example.local\DC1
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537     Account: (NULL)
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537     Options: 0x881
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: ReadOnly join requested.
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NETSETUP_MACHINE_PWD_PASSED passed, using lpPassword to authenticate as machine
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpDisableIDNEncoding: no domain dns available - IDN encoding will NOT be disabled
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDisableIDNEncoding returned: 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: status of connecting to dc '\\DC1': 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Passed DC 'DC1' NOT verified as DNS name '\\DC1.sub.example.local'
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Passed DC 'DC1' verified as Netbios name '\\DC1'
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662 NetpDsGetDcName: status of verifying DNS A record name resolution for 'DC1.sub.example.local': 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662 NetpGetDnsHostName: PrimaryDnsSuffix defaulted to DNS domain name: sub.example.local
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662 NetpProvisionComputerAccount:
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     lpDomain: sub.example.local
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     lpHostName: EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     lpMachineAccountOU: (NULL)
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     lpDcName: DC1
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     lpMachinePassword: (non-null)
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     lpAccount: sub.example.local\EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50$
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     lpPassword: (non-null)
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     dwJoinOptions: 0x9c1
05/20/2018 12:56:39:662     dwOptions: 0xc0000003
05/20/2018 12:56:39:709 NetpLdapBind: Verified minimum encryption strength on DC1.sub.example.local: 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:709 NetpLdapGetLsaPrimaryDomain: reading domain data
05/20/2018 12:56:39:709 NetpGetNCData: Reading NC data
05/20/2018 12:56:39:709 NetpGetDomainData: Lookup domain data for: DC=sub,DC=example,DC=local
05/20/2018 12:56:39:709 NetpGetDomainData: Lookup crossref data for: CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=sub,DC=example,DC=local
05/20/2018 12:56:39:709 NetpLdapGetLsaPrimaryDomain: result of retrieving domain data: 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:709 NetpCheckForDomainSIDCollision: returning 0x0(0).
05/20/2018 12:56:39:725 NetpValidateMachineAccount: Server negotiated options 0x1004000: 0x0
05/20/2018 12:56:39:725 NetpProvisionComputerAccount: status of validating account: 0x0
(truncated)
```

One interesting difference in this log is that the resolved **Account** is null:

```
05/20/2018 12:56:39:537     Account: (NULL)
```

Comment: Based on the documentation, when you specify the `PasswordPass` and the `Unsecure` options, that is how it's used to authenticate.  Also, when you look at the docs for the [NetJoinDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370433.aspx) API, which I presume is what `Add-Computer` is based on, the corresponding `NETSETUP_MACHINE_PWD_PASSED` and `NETSETUP_JOIN_UNSECURE` option flags seem to reinforce this idea based on my interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the issue was that `Add-Computer` cmdlet was getting confused and trying to pass both user and machine credentials.

When experimenting directly with the underlying [NetJoinDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370433.aspx) Windows API, you have to specify a `null` value for the `lpAccount` parameter when you use the equivalent of the `PasswordPass` option, since the authentication is using the machine credential instead of a user account.

So to do the same thing with the cmdlet, you have use an empty `UserName` in the `PSCredential` object.  Here is the updated, working example:

```
## This is just to confirm the expected hostname for this code sample
if ((& hostname) -ne 'EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50') {
    throw "Unexpected hostname!"
}

$password = 'FOOBARNON'
$passwordSS = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
## The only way to force a null username
$passCred = New-Object PSCredential([pscustomobject]@{
    UserName = $null
    ## Not really sure why we need to index this, but it's necessary,
    ## anybody have any thoughts???
    Password = $passwordSS[0]
})

Add-Computer -DomainName "sub.example.local" -Options UnsecuredJoin,PasswordPass -Credential $passCred
```

Comment: I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/pull/2447) to clarify the PowerShell docs on the use of the `PasswordPass` option for the `Add-Computer` cmdlet, which should hopefully clarify things for others in the future.

Comment: The clarified usage is now [live](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1) in the PowerShell docs, along with a new usage example (#9).

Answer (score 0):

I have not used these functionalities before, but I would have a guess at thinking the resulting secure string from `ConvertTo-SecureString` is encoded differently on the 2 devices the command is being run from, so my guess is that it's an incorrect password.

You could have a go at testing the AD credential for the machine account with the password you've earlier supplied to validate the password.

```
function Test-ADCredential
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [string]$UserName,
        [string]$Password
    )

    If (!($UserName) -or !($Password))
    {
        Write-Warning 'Test-ADCredential: Please specify both user name and password'
    }
    Else
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
        $DS = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('domain')
        $DS.ValidateCredentials($UserName, $Password)
    }
}


Test-ADCredential -UserName "EC2AMAZ-P9HUK50" -Password "FOOBARNON"
```

Additionally, perhaps try using these passwords in their plain text format as opposed to supplying secure strings to confirm the process is correct before adding that level of obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but no, that's not relevant.  I'm not the one _deciding_ to use obfuscation.  Those cmdlets require `[securestring]` arguments, there's no way around that. Secure Strings are encoded the same as far as the encryption process. The encoding is unique for each process/user on each machine as they use the Data Protect API to encrypt data with user-specific or process-specific encryption keys, however the mechanism is symmetric so it uses the same key as long as it's operating in the same process.

Comment: BTW, just to rule it out, I did run your code on both an already domain-joined host and the target server trying join and confirmed the password is correct in both cases.  FYI, 2 changes needed to be made to your code, appending the hostname with '$' -- that is the real SAM Account Name of a domain-joined computer, and allowing an optional domain name as the second argument to the `PrincipalContext` constructor.

Comment: Ah yes, very good. The code was left over from a test I was was doing on plain text credentials I scraped in open access file systems, sorry I didn't scrutinize it further than that use case. Best of luck with the unsecure join, I wish I could be more help. Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason for not using a secure join process?

Comment: This is part of an automation process that won't have any human actors involved in the actual domain join.  A privileged process is going to pre-create a computer account in the directory with a fixed hostname and temporary "join password".  Then on the newly provisioned host, all that will be available will be the host's name and the join password.

Comment: Interesting approach, best of luck

Comment: Just to provide a little bit more context, this approach was inspired by a feature that AWS offers to allow [automated domain joining](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_join_instance.html) for when spinning up a Windows VM, however their feature is restricted to only Windows hosts and only when joining an AWS-managed MSAD instance.  We've taken the same idea and applied it to manually-managed MSAD setup and it supports both Windows and Linux hosts.